# python code to run main.js and require.js files

Tags: javascript, python, html

can anyone help me to run js files by using python code for example
`<script data-main="main.js" src="require.js"></script>`
I want to write/convert this code into python

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the same using PyV8 where just write your js code in between the quotes:

```
import PyV8

context = PyV8.JSContext()
context.enter()

js = """Write your javascript code here"""
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply but i want to run multi js files can u help me with that ...

Comment: Your current question is just writing a  javascript in python and I think it helped. If you want for multi js files then please raise a new question so that it is easy for the  community to help each other. Also please make this answer and upvote if it solved your question.

Comment: actually, 2 js files (main.js and require.js) as I mentioned in the question (code)

Comment: why dont you write this js code directly by creating two python variables and  call them one by one. This way you can call multiple js codes together using python.